# How do you get the distribution of an IID?

Tags: statistics

If U1 and U2 are iid Unif(0,1) what is the distribution of -.5ln[(1-U1)U2]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Comment: i tagged with statistics